# Unity C# Ban UnityEvent.Invoke() outside class that contains it

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, events

is there a solution to ban UnityEvent.Invoke() method **outside class** that have this event?

Let's say I have an event, that should Invoke() only with some special conditions. I don't want other scripts to have the ability to invoke it manually. Is there a solution for this kind of situations?

*Other scripts can subscribe to this event, but never Invoke() it.*

```
public class Unit : MonoBehaviour
{
    // Invoke, with some internal secret conditions
    // NEVER use Invoke() outside this class!!! 
    public UnityEvent PrivateInvokeEvent { get; }

    /* ... Some logic that invoke PrivateInvokeEvent ... */
}

public class RandomClass
{
    private Unit _unit = new Unit();

    UnitManager() 
    {
        // You can do this:
        _unit.AddListener(()=>Debug.Log("Foo");

        // You SHOULD NOT do this:
        _unit.Invoke();
    }
}
```

Comment: Change `PrivateInvokeEvent` to `private UnityEvent _privateInvokeEvent` and define a method  say `public Fire()` in which _you_ fire the event but only under _"special conditions"_.

Comment: @MickyD but if PrivateInvokeEvent is private, then RandomClass can't subscribe to him by AddListener(). I need other classes to listen PrivateInvokeEvent. It is kind of like a traffic light. I want other classes (for example, class Car) to have the ability to subscribe to ChangeColor() event. But Cars should not have the ability to change it color, only subscribe to event. Because it could lead to bad situations

Comment: You can wrap AddListener up in your own method that others can call.   Don't expose the event to callers.